# Is it possible to prevent to startup of applications?

Tags: c#, windows, antimalware

TLDR; Just like Voodooshield or other application whitelisters do.

I want to prevent apps from spawning or if not possible kill them as soon as they spawn. So my question is: would it be possible to subscribe and interfere the spawn process with C# or (more likely) with the win32 API?

Comment: It is done with a Driver and [CreateProcessNotifyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff542860%28v%3Dvs.85%29)

Answer (score -1):

You can get all running processes using the `Process` class in `System.Diagnostics`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {

            foreach (var item in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                /*Kills all chrome.exe processes*/
                /*Replace chrome with the process you want to kill*/
                if (item.ProcessName == "chrome")
                {
                    //Kills the process
                    item.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```